# Kotlin extension function of a function with receiver

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions, typing, receiver, extension-function

I'm playing with Kotlin's extension functions.
I'd like to create an extension function for boolean-returning function with receivers which returns the complement function.

My goal is to be able to write:

```
val isEven: Int.() -> Boolean = { this % 2 == 0 }
val isOdd: Int.() -> Boolean = isEven.complement()
```

I do realize there are better, clearer ways for doing what I'm doing, I want to better understand the language itself here, so please don't tell me to write `isOdd` as `{ !isEven() }` :)

I want something like:

```
fun <I> (I.() -> Boolean).complement(): I.() -> Boolean = TODO()
```

Now,

```
fun <I> (I.() -> Boolean).complement(): I.() -> Boolean = this
```

compiles correctly, so the syntax definitely makes sense here. The problem is that `this` is of type `I.() -> Boolean`, and I'd need to access the "inner receiver" of my function with receiver, something like `this@this`, to write something like:

```
fun <I> (I.() -> Boolean).complement(): I.() -> Boolean = { !(this@this).this() }
```

where `this@this` would be of type `I`. Is there any way of achieving this effect?

Also, I noticed that I do not know how to invoke a function with receiver, I tried to:

```
fun <I> (I.() -> Boolean).complement(innerthis: I): I.() -> Boolean = { !this(innerthis) }
```

I get an `error: expression 'this' of type 'I' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found`.

This sounds wrong to me! `this` should have type `I.() -> Boolean`, not `I`! I can't wrap my head around this error message.

I thought that maybe I'm just using a wrong syntax, so I changed to:

```
fun <I> (I.() -> Boolean).complement(innerthis: I): I.() -> Boolean = { !innerthis.this() }
```

But I get the same error. This is very confusing to me, as I'd expected `innerthis` to by of type `I`, and `this` of type `I.() -> Boolean`.
My expectation seems to be confirmed by the implementation with `= this` to be compiling flawlessly.

Can someone explain to me the error the compiler is raising?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disambiguate the outer `this` by the function name:

```
fun <I> (I.() -> Boolean).complement(): I.() -> Boolean = { !this@complement(this) }
```

Here `this@complement` is the receiver of `complement` function, and plain `this` is the receiver of the lambda function literal. For simplicity, `this@complement` is called like a function with one argument, however it is possible to call it as an extension function as well using a bit more tricky syntax:

```
fun <I>  (I.() -> Boolean).complement(): I.() -> Boolean = { !this.(this@complement)() }
```

Comment: FYI: If you type `this` into IntelliJ, it actually suggests both `this : I` and `this@complement : I.() -> Boolean`; it's a very smart IDE! Definitely helps getting your head around it.

Comment: Thanks! That's it. The root of my mistake was into considering `this` as being bound to the outermost receiver, while in fact it yields the *innermost* receiver, hence allowing for disambiguation via `@` syntax.

Also, I didn't know the second syntax you proposed. Thanks again.

Comment: @AjahnCharles yes, but I usually prefer to exercise language features within a REPL, in order to force myself into reasoning on types without the help I usually get from an IDE -- which I agree, would have helped a lot in this case.